How can I use a second order polynomial in the first stage of an instrumental variable estimation in feols?
My fuzzy RD model with a linear first stage looks like this:
feols(fml = outcome ~ 1| 
          fe1 + fe2 |
          distance*treatment ~ 
          distance*above,
      cluster="clustervar", 
      data = data)

distance is the distance to the threshold, above is an indicator for being above the threshold, and treatment is an indicator for the treatment status.
Now I want to use a second order polynomial instead of the linear first stage.
How can I implement this?
